# How to protect files created/imported by composer?

Tags: php, deployment, composer-php

I just installed `composer` to manage my project's dependencies.

But I end up with a problem: **how to protect the files that `composer` created?**

Shouldn't there be an `.htaccess` file at the root of `vendor`? (for my case at the root of the `libsproduction` folder)

Here is my `composer.json` file :

```
{
  "config": { 
    "vendor-dir": "libsproduction/" 
  },
  "require": {
    "spipu/html2pdf": "^5.2",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.1",
    "tinymce/tinymce": "^5.2",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Composer files (both the `vendor` directory and the `composer.json` and `composer.lock` files themselves) shouldn't be in a publicly accessible place.

But the way to do this is not to create an `.htaccess` or something similar under a webserver different from Apache. What you should do is serve a directory different than the one containing these directory and files. Nor changing the `vendor` name as you are doing.

The way this is generally done, by most (if not all) composer based frameworks, is to create a "public" or "web" directory which is the one you would configure your web server to actually serve, and put your application entry file(s) there.

E.g.

```
project-root-dir
├── public
│  └── index.php
├── vendor/
├── composer.json
├── composer.lock
```

The directory your web server should point to would be `public` in this scenario. So visiting users cannot directly see anything that's not within that directory.

To load composer's autoloader so that all packages classes are available, you simply do something like:

```php
// public/index.php
require dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

/* your application/script logic goes here /*
```

This way you can also put any other file that shouldn't be user accessible (configuration, logs, cache, etc) one level up from the publicly accessible directory, and you have work less to protect your sensitive files.

Comment: Currently I do not have this tree, in the root folder I have all my folders: assets (with all my css, js), class, config (with all my config file), views, vendor (libsproduction), etc. So I have to move most of my files to a public folder (assests, class, config and views)? And make an .htaccess redirect to the public folder (so that it is considered as the root)

Comment: No `.htaccess` required. Just configure your webserver so that `public` is the root directory (instead of the project's root directory). Pointing the webserver to the project's root and **then** reading an `.htaccess` file it's wasteful.

Comment: You will need to make a few changes to your current directory layout, but I guess that's the reason you asked the question. :)

Comment: Indeed I am trying to greatly improve my way of working, I will also make another question about composer you may also have the answer

Comment: But how to use a javascript library with your solution (https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#composer) because I need to put the direct link to the ``.js`` file

Comment: Assets like JS, CSS and images can be put on `public`, since this need be served directly to clients. E.g. `public/assets/js`, `public/assets/css`, `public/assets/img`, etc. I wouldn't use composer to manage front-end dependencies. TinyMCE seems to be simply a JS script you can download and put where you need it. And if you want to handle front-end dependencies, use a tool specialized in that.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to use composer because several libraries js offer it, so how do I keep all of these libraries up to date without composer? (bootstrap, datatables, jquery, etc.)